# Is there a colour that displays the word "sullen"?

Tags: nouns

I have maroon and cool red in mind, but I'm not really sure. I need help with this problem. Identifying what problem it is was hard.

Comment: There's the well known 'dark is angry / sullen' metaphor, and red has been associated with anger. I'd suggest you google "Meaning of colours".